# Getting Identifier expected in Pycharm when importing a file

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am trying to import information from other files in other folders, but my program keeps stating 'Identifier expected'

```
from builtins import object
import os
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '0, 30'
from folder1 import 'splash text.txt*'
splashget = open('splash text.txt', 'r')
splashget = splashget.readlines()
splashtextchoice = random.choice(splashget)
screenwidth = 1920
screenheight = 1080
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
```

my file structure is organized like this:

```
Project
|
-----App
|
-----Folder1
       |
       -------splash text.txt
```

The error appears at **from folder1 import 'splash text.txt*'** on the first apostrophe. This text file has several small phrases on it, each one on a new line. Any help fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

The `import` statement is used to make a `.py` file's classes, their methods, and/or functions available to you in a different `.py` file. You cannot import `.txt` files, you open them with the `open()` function (either with `with open()` or `f = open(...)`). You're doing the latter already, but you also have to account for directories (that being `Folder1`) containing the file you wish to access, so I recommend you do this:

```py
# with the with context manager

with open('Folder1/splash text.txt', 'r') as splashget:
    # do code stuff here
```

```py
# with the f = open(...) method

splashget = open('Folder1/splash text.txt', 'r')
# do code stuff here
splashget.close()
```

Either of these will open `splash text.txt` in the file you're in specifically. (See the note below on why adding `Folder1/` in front allows us to open the file.)

Note: `'Folder1/splash text.txt'` is a relative file path (as in how to get to the file/directory you want from the file you're in), Python will do the logic necessary to convert this to an absolute file path (how to get from the top of the drive to the file/directory you want, ex. from `C:` to `Folder1`)